# Keep xcom variables between reschedules in airflow?

Tags: airflow

I'm creating a custom sensor. It used to work in versions like 2.0.2.
The trick was doing something like this:

```
def poke(self, context):
request_id = context['ti'].xcom_pull(key="requestId", task_ids=self.task_id + "_original", dag_id=self.dag_id)
if request_id is None:
    self.log.info("requestId not found, so we launch the Lambda function")
    request_id = self.launch_lambda()

    # To avoid task reschedule clean the xcom message, we use the XCom API directly to push the requestId
    # but with a taskId modified
    XCom.set(
        key="requestId",
        value=request_id,
        task_id=self.task_id + "_original",
        dag_id=self.dag_id,
        execution_date=context['ti'].execution_date)
    self.log.info("Pushed requestId %s to xcom", request_id)
```

However now in 2.5.3, cause this "{task}_original" task doesnt exist it throws this exception:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.ForeignKeyViolation) insert or update on table "xcom" violates foreign key constraint "xcom_task_instance_fkey"

DETAIL:  Key (dag_id, task_id, run_id, map_index)=(performance_1_batchsensor_dev, eks-airflow-batchsensor_job_laucher_task_1_original, manual__2023-09-07T16:51:33.660188+00:00, -1) is not present in table "task_instance".
```

So seems that in Airflow 2.5.3 you cannot put in XCOM variables using a non existing task_id

Any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

There is no workaround for using this approach with xcom after 2.2. We were using this approach in 2.2, but it's been patched since 2.3 or 2.4; best bet around it is to use Deferrable Sensor and write a custom Trigger. Triggers have a `serialize` function which persists data on deferring.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was also frustrated by this, and finally found the reason for this behavior in the airflow [XCom docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/xcoms.html):

> If the first task run is not succeeded then on every retry task XComs will be cleared to make the task run idempotent.

So the XCom is cleared every time `poke` returns `False`